# Iterating a list of object in object

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, foreach

I'm trying to go through a list of objects which contain another list of objects.

In the image posted below, you'll see how a object looks like and how the `forEach` behaves.

My code :

```
myApp.controller('Hello', [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/projects').success(function(data) {
        $scope.projects = data;
        angular.forEach($scope.projects,function(allMsr){
            console.log(allMsr);
            angular.forEach(allMsr, function(key,val){
                console.log("Got into the 2nd for");
                if(key = "files")
                    console.log(val+" "+key);
            })
        })

    });
}
```

The output:
[image: This is how to object looks like and the console after running]

What I'm trying to do is to use the `key` and `val` fields in each object contained by `allMsr`.

Comment: You're trying to iterate on `project.allMsr`, but there is no such `project` variable defined. You named the current project in the outer loop `allMsr`.

Comment: @JB Nizet. That's my bad, tried to see if it's working that way. When I delete that is not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach): the arguments of the function passed to `angular.forEach()` are `value` and `key`, not `key` and `value`.

And that is the syntax to use when iterating over the key/value pairs of an object. But `allMsr` is not an object, it's an array. So what you want is something like

```
angular.forEach(allMsr, function(obj) {
    console.log("Got into the 2nd for");
    if (obj.key === "files") {
        console.log(obj.val + " " + obj.key);
    }
});
```

Note that `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator.

Comment: Actually I'm using `val` and `key` because those are the fields I need from `allMsr`.

Comment: So, allMsr is an array, and not an object, right, and each element of this array is an object with two fields named val and key, right?

Comment: the objects in the `allMsr` array have more then two fields. But `val` and `key` are the ones I need.